# BPMN Test Designer

Tags: jbpm, activiti, bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

I have a bunch of BPMN processes using Camunda. I want to know if I can design some test scenarios for those BPMN files using a modeler.

I know Camunda and other BPMN engines have some features to write tests using Java or some other languages. But I want to know if I, as a BPMN designer, who doesn't have any experience in programming, can design my test scenarios just like the way I design the BPMN itself(without writing code by using a modeler).

The question is not restricted to Camunda only. I would like to know if any other BPMN engines like jBPM or Activiti have such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest challenges with ANY low code environment is the development and implementation of unit and integration tests. Camunda and its predecessor Activiti include "mock" implementations specifically for testing, but you need basic Java skills in order to write these tests. Unfortunately I am not aware of any real solution to your problem.
What you CAN do, and somethign I have done in the past is to "mitigate" the problem by breaking your processes up into smaller unit modules. These can be wrapped inside "test" processes. The test process can produce test data which the module processes and the results can be verified.